# Обломов и... облом

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Подумалось: а сленговое слово "облом" в значении "лень", "не охота" имеет отношение к гончаровскому Обломову?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переносное жаргонное ОБЛОМ - не "лень",а "неудача"("лень"- в лом), а в Обломове главная черта не эта, хотя фамилия всё равно говорящая. Обломов - от слова «обло» - круг. Это замкнутость, внутренняя жизнь, внешнее спокойствие. Фамилию хочется произнести медленно, выговаривая каждый звук «о».

А вообще-то в этом романе есть много говорящих фамилий: фамилия Махов сближается с глаголом подмахнуть, фамилия Затертый мотивируется глаголом затереть в значении "замять дело", а фамилия Вытягушин - устойчивым сочетанием вытягивать душу. Фамилия Пенкин ассоциируется не только со словом пена (в значении "пузырчатая масса на поверхности жидкости, образующаяся от сильного взбалтывания, брожения"; переносно - о рассчитанной на внешний эффект, но бессмысленной по сути бурной деятельности) и пениться (в переносном значении "сильно возбуждаться, горячиться"), но и фразеологизмами снимать пенки и с пеной у рта. Фамилия Мухояров сближается со словом мухрыга - "продувной обманщик и плут" и напоминает о яром (то есть интенсивном) мельтешении мух. Наименование Тарантьев мотивируется  диалектным глаголом тарантить ("тараторить, говорить бойко, скоро").

Comment: Фантастика... Откуда такие дровишки? Народная этимология?
А Штольц?

Я, признаться, "Обломова" не очень жалую, больно уж главный герой карикатурный, но всё-таки читывал. До такого примитивизма не додумался.

Comment: Не знаю, что Вы называете примитивизмом, это мнение профессоров филологии. Я занималась в гончаровском семинаре, профессор Киреева говорила о контаминации значений: "обломок прошлого" и "облый" -
" замкнутый круг".Вот ещё мнения:http://bibliofond.ru/view.aspx?id=553151Уже в самом названии романа прослеживается очень сложная концепция главного героя. «Обло» - это круг, блаженствующий круг. А с другой стороны - это «обломок» пиршенственного стола жизни.
http://www.gramma.ru/LIT/?id=1.119
http://www.xliby.ru/literaturovedenie/filologicheskii_analiz_teksta_uchebnoe_posobie/p8.php

Comment: Примитивизмом я назвал интерепетацию фамилий героев. Обломова самого не касался. Тут действительно не примитивизм. Но касательно самой идеи найти что-то говорящее в его фамилии - остаюсь при своих. Статьи посмотрю позже.

Первая ссылка - битая.
А Грамма - это большой филологический гайд-парк. Сам факт публикации там ровным счетом ничего не говорит. Скорее наоборот. В том смысле, что там оказываются вещи и авторы, которых просто нигде не приняли.

Киреева - это Ирина Васильевна?

Answer (score 2):

Вспомнила эпиграф к книге «Путешествие из Петербурга в Москву»: « Чудище обло, озорно, огромно, стозевно и лаяй». «Обло» ещё и «тучное»

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это перевод Вергилия Тредиаковским. 
Но вот это интересно. Обломов наверняка именно от этого значения. Правда я склонен даже в этом случае считать совпадением. В говорящие фамилии у Гончарова по-прежнему не слишком вериться.

А нет, пардон. Если от Обло - то М там не мотивировано получается.

Answer (score 1):

Фантастика... Откуда такие дровишки? Народная этимология? А Штольц?

Stolz (нем.) *гордый*. Гордый, видимо, своей деловитостью. 
По мне, так лучше размышления об общем благе, чем деловитость, направленная лишь к собственной выгоде.))))

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли. Сленговое значение явно моложе Ильи Ильича. 
Да и не в духе Гончарова давать "говорящие" фамилии своим героям.

Comment: Обрыв, Обломов, Обыкновенная история... Гончаров просто пошутил.

Comment: В ваша тёща - она ... шутить не любила?

Answer (score 0):

Интересно дальнейшее развитие.
"Синяя птица обломинго помахала мне крылом..."
Поэтично, не правда ли?  ;)